# n x n Matrix Puzzle

Tags: arithmetic, puzzle

You are given an n×n square matrix to be ﬁlled with numerals so that no two adjacent cells have the same numeral. Two cells are called adjacent if they touch each other horizontally, vertically or diagonally. So a cell in one of the four corners has three cells adjacent to it, and a cell in the ﬁrst or last row or column which is not in the corner has five cells adjacent to it. Any other cell has eight cells adjacent to it.

What is the minimum number of different numerals needed to ﬁll a 5×5 square matrix?

I tried, and I came up with the answer 5 but the answer that has been provided is 4. Can anyone please tell me how one can get to 4? What will be the arrangement?

Comment: Start with 3X3 .. then go for 4X4 ... then 5X5

Comment: for 3x3 i got 4 and it was correct....the same approach i applied for 5x5 and starting from the corners and then moving inwards...but i ended up with 5 as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 &3  &0  &3  &0 \\ 
2 &1  &2  &1  &2 \\ 
0 &3  &0  &3  &0 \\ 
2 &1  &2  &1  &2 \\ 
0 &3  &0  &3  &0 
\end{bmatrix}$$
which uses only $0,1,2,$ and $3$.

Comment: ok..i realised my mistake...i was doing a silly mistake... i was taking the center piece to be different number of what is present in the corners....thanks for such a quick response!

Comment: @Ali Note that this extends to any size region. Each row has 2 alternating colours, and adjacent rows use a different pair of colours.